# change <title> tag based upon folder filename

Tags: php

This is how I had arranged the folders:

```
--Page -
       |--admin--
       |         |-->functions.php
       |
       |--movie--
       |         | --> movie.php
       |
       |-->index.php
```

I have all the functions inside functions.php, this is the "title" function:

```
//CHANGE PAGE <title> TAG
function title($text = __DIR__)
{
    $title = basename($text);
    $title = ucwords(str_replace($title,$title,$title));
    return $title;
}
```

and this page is movie.php inside movie folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <title><?php echo title(); ?></title>
</head>
```

The result output is`admin` . I need the output to be `movie` . As you can see, title shows the "admin" folder as a result, not the "movie" folder.

If I change the `title` function inside the title tag in movie.php with `title(__DIR__)`, it works, but I want to do that without writing `__DIR__` inside the `title()` function, that's why when I created the title function I wrote : `function title($text =__DIR__)` but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: you have to pass `__DIR__` in. thats kinda a static for that file.

Comment: it returns admin because the functions.php is inside the admin folder

Comment: @DanielA.White you're right, but do you if there is a way to have the same title(__DIR__) result without writing __DIR__ inside the function?

Comment: i don't think so - the function call has no context of who called it.

Comment: run your `function.php` in `movie.php` you will get title as movie since function is ruined inside movie **if this is bad idea am sorry**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns admin because the function called is inside functions.php which is inside the admin folder

Instead of  the function just do this:

```
<title><?php echo basename(__DIR__); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I would recommend this, but you could use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get full path to the file that called the function, and extract the folder it is in.

```
function title() {
    //Get the backtrace, limited to one calling function.
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace( null, 1 );
    //Sanity check, just to be safe.
    if ( isset( $backtrace[0]['file'] ) ) {
        return basename( dirname( $backtrace[0]['file'] ) );
    }
    return '';
}
```